# SSH host-keys: "ssh-keygen -H" vs "ssh-keyscan"

Tags: ssh

"ssh-keygen -F " seems to return one host-key for a given hostname (first matched?), and "ssh-keyscan " seems to return all matched, but the order is not clear.

What's the specific difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `ssh-keygen(1)` manpage:

> ```
> -H      Hash a known_hosts file.  This replaces all hostnames and addresses with hashed
>         representations within the specified file; the original content is moved to a
>         file with a .old suffix.  These hashes may be used normally by ssh and sshd, but 
>         they do not reveal identifying information should the file's contents be 
>         disclosed.  This option will not modify existing hashed hostnames and is 
>         therefore safe to use on files that mix hashed and non-hashed names.
> ```

and from the `ssh-keyscan(1)` manpage:

> ```
> -H      Hash all hostnames and addresses in the output.  Hashed names may be used 
>         normally by ssh and sshd, but they do not reveal identifying information should
>         the file's contents be disclosed.
> ```

The former rums *locally*, hashing your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, while the latter contacts a *remote* server to request its keys.

Comment: Obviously, I meant "-F", rather than "-H". Thank you for your final note, though. The docs don't seem to be explicit about this.